# Conditional formatting on list script

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, formatting

I used the above code to apply a background color on a line with the word High in a field (choice). It does not work. I have used a code that matches exactly the word as in other fields (descriptions etc) there might be written the word High in other contexts.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("td .ms-vb2").filter( function (index) {

       return $(this).text() == "High";

    })
$Text.parent().css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");

});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it related to SharePoint? if not, it should be asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: SharePoint version?

Comment: online...........

Answer (score 0):

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Instead you can try this (**Applies to classic List Views only**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("td.ms-vb2").each( function () {

       if($(this).text() == "High"){
       $(this).parent("tr").css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");
       //$(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", "#F5A9A9");
       }      


    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: I was able to use your code with 4 different words and 4 different colors. Am I right in thinking that because you have put '==' (strictly equal to the word in the string) it means that if there is a comment field in the table and by chance there is a sentence that includes the world 'High' (among other words) it will not trigger the color change?

Comment: Correct. The IF condition in the above code is looking for an exact match with in the matched TAG. There is a different way to check the occurrence of a word - check here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp